# parse string table from my process output

Tags: c#

i receives this table from my process output into `List<string>`:

[image]

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
StreamReader reader = tsharkProcess.StandardOutput;

            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string read = reader.ReadLine();
                list.Add(read);
            }
```

what would be the best way to parse this table to show only the ip address, the value and the parentage ?

Comment: Is this tab delimited? If so, you can just split on `\t`.

Comment: Do you really need the best way or any-way is enough?

Comment: i dont think the limiter is tab and what i have try is 3 Dictionary<string, double> but it would be bad idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will read the ipAddress, value and percentage on the fly if the rows are tab-delimited

```
using(StreamReader reader = tsharkProcess.StandardOutput)
{
   while (!reader.EndOfStream)
   {
       string[] values = reader.ReadLine().Split('\t');
       if (values.Length == 4)
       {
           string ipAddress = values[0];
           string value = values[1];
           string percentage = values[3];
           ...
       }
   }
}
```

If not then it could be done using RegEx.

```
using(StreamReader reader = tsharkProcess.StandardOutput)
{
   while (!reader.EndOfStream)
   {
       string row = reader.ReadLine();
       string[] values = Regex.Split(row, @"\s+", RegexOptions.None);
       if (values.Length == 4)
       {
           string ipAddress = values[0];
           string value = values[1];
           string percentage = values[3];
           ...
       }
   }
}
```

And the hard core RegEx solution.

```
public class MyClass
{
    // Lots of code....

    private static Regex regexRowExtract = new Regex(@"^\s*(?<ip>\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s*(?<value>\d+)\s+(?<rate>\d+\.?\d*)\s+(?<percentage>\d+\.?\d*)%\s*$", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public void ReadSharkData()
    {
        using(StreamReader reader = tsharkProcess.StandardOutput)
        {
            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                string row = reader.ReadLine();
                Match match = regexRowExtract.Match(row);
                if (match.Success)
                {
                    string ipAddress = match.Groups["ip"].Value;
                    string value = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                    string percentage = match.Groups["percentage"].Value;

                    // Processing the extracted data ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For the Regex solution you should use:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

Comment: "\s+" Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: You should use @"\s+", sorry for forgetting a @

Comment: i need to declare the line static Regex regexRowExtract(...) in other way ? (2 errors received: 1. Expected ; or = (cannot specify constructor arguments in declaration) 2. The modifier 'static' is not valid for this item)

Comment: The static regexRowExtract is defined as part of the class, that way it is only created once, the first time you use the class - sorry for not writing the entire class definition.

Comment: i have build an object that hold this 3 values (ip, value and %), how can i order it in List in descending order ?

Comment: Great idea to hold the 3 values in an object.  To order the objects you should have a look at IComparable and implement a CompareTo method.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with regex, maybe not the best but one way to solve it.

Regex for IP

```
\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b
```

I didn't serach for any regex for percent, but I think it not will be so hard.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a regex expression, which will match distinct values from a row, and parse the file line by line. It should be relatively easy because all your values are separated by whitespaces.